# .ocx usage by a WCF service (running on IIS)

Tags: wcf, iis, ocx

I am writing a WCF service that starts a windows form application. This windows form application calls methods of an old .ocx file and return the results to WCF service through pipelines.
When I run the service using visual studio everything is ok, but when I publish the WCF service and deploy it on IIS, the ocx method calls in windows form application don't work!!!.

Comment: Many Active X control only works in an application running in user sessions, which WCF on IIS is not. Ask the vendor/developers of that control for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lex Li for your comment, 
The problem was due to different sessions of the application and the service. When I changed the identity of my pool in IIS to my user session, the problem was resolved.